# ModX revo Missing System Settings after restoring on localhost

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Basically took a backup from server and restored it on my machine. Everything seems to be displaying correctly. But when I go to my System Settings, there are missing settings. But when I check modx_system_settings, they're there. Also cleared cache multiple times, so that's not the issue it seems.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for my case. Basically it was server related. Live server is using linux, so when I set it up on my local which is wondows based, I had to search systems settings in DB for "locale" and update the value to English. That fixed my system settings. Everything showing now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the you crosschecked the same database tables? Is the  table modx_system_settings the same table that MODX installation has in use?

Another possibility could be a not writable cache file in core/cache/system_settings or core/cache/context_settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I found the issue with my case.

Answer (score 0):

there is a cache_system_settings and cache_context_settings... though if you have cleared cache multiple times.  actually delete the files to verify. Is it possible that you have context settings that would be overriding system settings? It would be helpful to tell us what settings are "missing"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I found the issue with my case.